# Whats does gfortrans -ftree-pre do?

Tags: gfortran

I"m tracking down an issue where I get different result depending on whether I use -O2 or -O1. Bisecting the compile options enabled by -O2 and not -O1, shows that I need to add -ftree-pre to -O1 to get the same results as using -O2. The gfortran documentation states that:

```
-ftree-pre

Perform partial redundancy elimination (PRE) on trees. This flag is enabled by default at -O2 and -O3.
```

[gfortran 9.2 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Can someone explain what this means? And if possible, what kind of code (for instance OO, pointers, arrays etc or something else) might be affected by this? This is for gfortran v9.2.0